# Displaying number of unread Message of a conversation in a table View

Tags: ios, swift

I want to display the number of unread messages of a conversation in a badge for each cell just like the yellow badges in the picture :

[Yellow bubble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZEu0.jpg)

Thanks !

Comment: Your question seams too broad. I guess you have to develop a webservice that give you the number of unread message, then you just have to display it. Last, you should import image in your message instead of paste a link

Comment: Can you provide some code or something you have tried?

Comment: I tried to put a label for each cell, but it didn't work, so i'm pretty lost for now

Comment: Show what you have tried. Specifically, show the code in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably for this kind of work you just need some extra effort by adding the one parameter in your listing of users in message tab(as image displayed) just add one parameter which gives unread message count of particular user. whenever you are displaying user list using tableview at that time you can check wether this user contain any unread messages or not if the count of unread message is not 0 so you need to display that count and if it is 0 at that time you just need to hide that unreadCountLabel.

Here is the snippet with swift 3. hope it helps you

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if self.aMessageUser.unreadMessage > 0{
            cell.lblUnreadMsgCount.isHidden = false
            cell.lblUnreadMsgCount.text = \(self.aMessageUser.unreadMessage)
        }
        else{
            cell.lblUnreadMsgCount.isHidden = true
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `var` that stores the number of unread messages. Then when in a `prepareforSegue`, set that variable to zero.